# Choosing speakers for a robot

Tags: speakers

I'm very new to digital audio. I bought [these microphones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09X3366RP). I would like to create an echo by speaking to a mic and playing it back using an ESP-32 WROOM board. When I choose speakers, what characteristics should I consider? Do I need any other components like amplifiers, DAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a high level, these would be the modules required:

1. Mic
2. Pre-amp
3. ADC
4. Processor
5. DAC
6. Amp
7. Speaker

It appears that 1-3 are included in the mic module that you bought.

You probably want to use an SPI DAC chip or module.

You can buy cheap little amp modules on Amazon that should meet your needs. Something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07Y4ZBNB2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Y4ZBNB2)

As for the amp and speaker, you need to trade off: available space, cost, and sound quality.

In the future, your questions should be more specific.